# Make a JSON-like structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I know I can use JSON to make this, but I must do it this way. 
I have a Google Map and I am pulling latitude coordinates and longitude coordinates from my Database(in C#).
Afterwards I am adding all those information in an ol(ordered list) in the HTML.
Now I have to pull them two by two and make a structure which is something like this:

```
stores1 = [{

            "lat": "12312.123",
            "lng": "2.21312",
            "state": "Potato"

        }, {

            "lat": "12321.11",
            "lng": "1.1",
            "state": "Potato2"


        }, {

            "lat": "2.32131",
            "lng": "4.4",
            "state": "Potato"

        }

        ]
```

I am using this code to do it:

```
var stores=[];
    //test list
    var listTMP = document.getElementById("listDealers");
    var list = listTMP.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++) {
        stores.push(
            {
                lat: list[i].innerText,
                lng: list[i + 1].innerText,
                state: "potato"
            }
            );
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

The i=i+1 is because i add the li(list items) in the form:

longitude1

latitude1

|

longitude2

latitude2

.... So the first two are together then the next two and so on...
But there is a problem my map isn't displaying the coordinates. The whole JavaScript works otherwise if I add static coordinates,but my problem is that I need them to be added dynamically like this. 
Any help? Where am I making a mistake?

Here is the c# code: (getList is my function to get the data)

```
string sqlL = "Select * from retailers";
string[] atrrL = { "LATITUDE" ,"LONGITUDE"}; 
List<String> tmpL = getList(sqlL, atrrL); 
for (int i = 0; i < tmpL.Count; i++) { 
    listDealers.InnerHtml +=( "<li>" + tmpL[i].ToString().Trim() + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: Just a style thing - if you change `i++` to `i += 2` and eliminate the second call to increment `i`, it will look cleaner and be more obvious that you did that on purpose.

Comment: I don't see anything here that is broken. You may have to just step through and see what that `stores` array looks like when it's populated. Maybe there's whitespace in the `innerText` that might be throwing off your number parsing, or maybe you've got a typo somewhere in your IDs.

Comment: The way you describe your problem, it sounds like you've got the raw data before building your `ol`. If that's the case, you'd be better off working with the raw data to build your JSON object, rather than writing it to HTML then reading the HTML to write to an object. It doesn't matter if you're building your `ol` from the server or client, either way, you've got the raw data and can create a JSON object from it.

Comment: And yes i tried to alert every coordinate 1 by 1 in the for cycle, and everything seems fine...the coordinates(strings are exactly the same they should be) but apparently the problem is somewhere in the stores.push();

Comment: I ran this with some simple data (`<ol id="listDealers"><li>123</li><li>456</li><li>789</li><li>2.34</li></ol>`), and the array was populated perfectly. Your `push` code is just fine, assuming you want the array you defined at the top of your page. If your array is populated properly and you're still having problems, the issue must be with the thing reading the array, not the array itself.

Comment: Thank you everyone I solved it. The problem was with the var stores=[]; I had to put that out of the document.ready() function.